# React client side validation with material-ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Some material-ui components have errorText as a prop which we can use to show errors, But, doing that in react become lot complex if my form has large number of field components.

Please suggest the best way to handle client-side validation with material-ui comonents.

Comment: In what way would it become complicated?

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you have to manage a lot with state/store. In react validation is complex because of one-way binding.

This library https://github.com/vishalvisd/react-validator is one which I found that supports material-ui component validation. Though in general you may use this to validate any component.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using some HoC (Higher-order Component) approach. I tested many solutions for form validation in React JS, the one that I always choose is: [react-validation-mixin](https://github.com/jurassix/react-validation-mixin). Take a look at this [example](https://jurassix.gitbooks.io/docs-react-validation-mixin/content/overview/es6-classes-flux.html).

Example of the standard input:

```
<input
  type='text'
  placeholder='Username'
  value={this.props.username}
  onChange={this.onChange('username')}
  onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('username')}
/>
```

In this example `value` of that input comes from `props` (example with Flux implementation) and that's probably what you aim for too (lots of inputs). 
`onChange` will need to handle value change so that `this.props.username` gets updated too and `onBlur` will trigger validation check (so that the error will show up once user leaves the input).

In order to get the error message, use: `this.props.getValidationMessages('username')`

It's a universal solution and you can use it in different libs. But taking `TextField` from `material-ui`, as you asked:

```
<TextField
  floatingLabelText="Username"
  value={this.props.username}
  errorText={this.props.getValidationMessages('username')}
  onChange={this.onChange('username')}
  onBlur={this.props.handleValidation('username')}
  ...
/>
```

Remember to use HoC with your component: `export default validation(strategy)(UserLogin)` That way, you will get all the necessary helper methods in `props`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Redux in React project, redux-form give you a simple way to implement form validation.

Check this out: http://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/syncValidation/